# How am I to convert the .txt file into dictionary - Python

Tags: python

I've a .txt file with the data in the following format:

```
{"user_id": "user_id", "category": "category"}
{"user_id": "123456789", "category": "Hardware"}
{"user_id": "987654321", "category": "Equipment"}
```

How am I to convert it to the following dictionary:

```
{"123456789":"Hardware"}
{"987654321":"Equipment"}
```

?

Comment: Okay, cool. How would you break this problem down? And where are you getting stuck? Do you know how to read a file? To iterate over its lines? To read JSON? Please read [ask].

Comment: (Side note: your expected output isn't _a_ dictionary, it's two dictionaries. Are you looking for one dict per data row? Should they be in a list or something?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first create a list to hold the data for you

second open the file and convert each line to a dictionary object

finally add the object to your list

( since you don't need the first line of your file, you may pop the first element of your list )

```
result = [] # for holding the data

with open('file','r') as data: # open your file in read mode

    for line in data.readlines(): # iterate over lines

        temp_json = json.loads(line) # create a dict object from each line upon every iteration 

        result.append({ temp_json['user_id'] : temp_json['category'] }) # append the object to your list 
    
result.pop(0) # pop the first element wich is { 'user_id':'category' }
```

Comment: Please don't write code for users if they don't provide their own. We're not here to do people's homework (or job) for them. We're here to help them _learn_ and providing code to blindly copy and paste doesn't help with that. See [answer]: "Not all questions can or should be answered here. Save yourself some frustration and avoid trying to answer questions which... are unclear or lacking specific details that can uniquely identify the problem."